# UIImageView content pixels (ingore image padding)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

The short version: How do I know what region of a UIImageView contains the image, and not aspect ratio padding?

The longer version:
I have a UIImageView of fixed size as pictured:

[image]

I am loading photos into this UIViewController, and I want to retain the original photo's aspect ratio so I set the contentMode to Aspect Fit. This ends up ensuring that the entire photo is displayed within the UIImageView, but with the side effect of adding some padding (configured in red):

[image]

No problem so far.... But now I am doing face detection on the original image. The face detection code returns a list of CGRects which I then render on top of the UIImageView (I have a subclassed UIView and then laid out an instance in IB which is the same size and offset as the UIImageView).

This approach works great when then photo is not padded out to fit into UIImageView. However if there is padding, it introduces some skew as seen here in green:

[image]

I need to take the image padding into account when rendering the boxes, but I do not see a way to retrieve it.

Since I know the original image size and the UIImageView size, I can do some algebra to calculate where the padding should be. However it seems like there is probably a way to retrieve this information, and I am overlooking it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use image views often so this may not be the best solution. But since no one else has answered the question I figured I'd through out a simple mathematical solution that should solve your problem:

```
UIImage *selectedImage; // the image you want to display
UIImageView *imageView; // the imageview to hold the selectedImage

NSInteger heightOfView = imageView.frame.size.height;
NSInteger heightOfPicture = selectedImage.size.height;

NSInteger yStartingLocationForGreenSquare; // set it to whatever the current location is

// take whatever you had it set to and add the value of the top padding
yStartingLocationForGreenSquare += (heightOfView - heightOfPicture) / 2;
```

So although there may be other solutions this is a pretty simple math formula to accomplish what you need. Hope it helps.